# Agregar atributo required a un textbox - ASP.net

Tags: html5, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

es posible agregar a un Textbox el atributo `required` en VB.net. Supondría que sería con algo así: `textbox.Attributes.Add("required")` o es necesario insetar JavaScript para implementarlo?

Answer (score 0):

usando el patron MVC, podrias agregar un Data Anotations en tu modelo que indique que ese dato es requerido.

```
[Required]
public string Nombre { get ; set}
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6

http://www.macoratti.net/13/12/c_vdda.htm